# Can I make a syslinux install to USB flash drive persistent using a persistent partition on the same drive?

Tags: usb, live-usb, unetbootin, persistence, mkusb

Since 14.04 I have not been able to create a persistent install, with the casper-rw partition on the same drive, with systems created using SDC, UNetbootin, Rufus, Universal, etc.

These USB installs all work with persistent partitions, but only if the casper-rw partition is located on a different drive, either USB or internal HDD.

I also know same drive persistent partitions work with grub2 type installs such as mkusb or MultiBootUSB make, but am specifically asking if anyone has gotten persistent partitions working with syslinux installs post 14.04.

Comment: I have the same experience and am also interested in a solution for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent partitions work with **YUMI**.

YUMI does syslinux a bit differently, (with a dash of grub4dos), substituting a casper-rw partition for a casper-rw file works, but is a little redundant as multiple persistent casper-rw files greater than 4GB are possible, while only one persistent partition is possible.

- Do not use the persistence option when making the USB.
- After install shrink the OS partition and make a new ext4 partition labeled casper-rw.
- Add the word persistent to /MULTIBOOT/multiboot/[OS ISO name]/grub.cfg just after "noprompt".

Windows data can be stored in a folder on the OS partition. It can be accessed by root in the isodevice folder when booted from the USB.